# Creating XML file from API with PHP forEach and SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to create XML File from API (in this case Instagram API).
But i face a problem since i create it with forEach function. Look at productName and productPrice attribute from product section:

```
<product productName="No Title" productID="001" thumbPath="http://IMAGE_URL" productPrice="0">
    <details>
        detail1
    </details>
</product>
<product productName="Sushi Homemade " productID="002" thumbPath="http://IMAGE_URL" productPrice="50.000 ">
    <details>
        detail2
    </details>
</product>
<product productName="Sushi Homemade " productID="003" thumbPath="http://IMAGE_URL" productPrice="50.000 ">
    <details>
        detail3
    </details>
</product>
```

Value productName="Sushi Homemade " and productPrice="50.000 " is just for productID="002". But why the value also filled to next productID >= 002.

Here's the snippet to creating xml with PHP. Maybe i've gonna wrong with it:

```
<products>
<category categoryName="Instagram">
    <?php foreach ($contents->data as $data) {

foreach($data->comments->data as $comment){
          if(preg_match('/#title/', $comment->text)){
          $komen = preg_replace('/#title/', '', $comment->text);
          break;
          } else { $komen = 'No Title'; }
}

foreach($data->comments->data as $comment){
          if(preg_match('/#price/', $comment->text)){
          $harga = preg_replace('/#price/', '', $comment->text);
          break;
          } else { $harga = '0'; }
}


          echo '<product productName="'. $komen .'" productID="' . $data->id . '" thumbPath="' . $data->images->thumbnail->url . '" productPrice="'. $harga .'">
        <details>
                    <![CDATA[
                    <img src="' . $data->images->low_resolution->url . '" width="100%"/>
        ' . $data->caption->text . '
                    ]]>
        </details>
</product>
```

Comment: What is your question, what doesn't work?

Comment: No, it's new different problem.
Look at for XML results: http://pastebin.com/ubGGyp9b (I can't paste xml formatted here). 
The problem is:
Value productName="Sushi Homemade " and productPrice="50.000 " is just for productID="002". But why the value also filled to next productID >= 002.